# Jenkins Job finishes successfully when Grunt task fails

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

How can I get a Jenkins job to fail if the Grunt task I am running does not finish successfully and print `Done, without errors`?  Right now, it keeps executing the rest of the commands.  Ideally, I would like the job to stop at that point and fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any exit code other than 0 will cause Jenkins to mark build step as failure

Comment: Ah.  I'm not a shell expert, but I think I figured it out.  For instance in bash, I can use `echo $?` to print the exit code of the last command.  Therefore I can get the exit code by declaring a variable `EXIT_CODE=$?` after the `grunt build` command. I do have other commands running after that which I want to stop if grunt fails.  I found that adding option e when declaring the shell at the top `#!/bin/bash -e` stops execution if any command fails.  Thanks.  That worked.

Comment: `EXIT_CODE=$?` will only store the exit code to variable. You need to *exit*: `exit n` will exit with value `n`. The `-e` option will make the script fail on any command failure... it's OK for simple scripts, but it also means you cannot perform any error checking/catching on your own, as it will fail out before it reaches the error evaluation part of your script

Comment: I used `exit 1` if grunt fails.  That works like a charm, thanks.  I had to do an if statement anyway.  It seems Envject plugin doesn't play nice with `-e` as I am also injecting environment variables with a `.properties` file.